# Airflow create dag api or function

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

Is there any API or function available which can create DAG in airflow on demand ? We have more than thousand DAG's on DagBag folder and it takes substantial time for scheduler to scan and therefore performance is degrading. We have increased time to scan DagBag folder to 1 day in order to control this behavior but every new DAG created requires scheduler restart, which we would like to avoid.
Please advise.

Comment: did you go through [DAG serialization](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/dag-serialization.html)? BTW `"..and therefore performance is degrading.."` does that refer to `scheduler` or `webserver`?

Comment: Performance issue is related to scheduler. Pls advise further.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably do following things:

- Have all your core logic in the dags moved to a callable functions
- And have a generic Dag which will call those functions holding your core logic and execute at a given specific time

You will need to save the list of your core functions and the execution time somewhere (could be a database or some file you can read)

This will be a case of having a small schedule on top of airflow, which is redundant as airflow does the same thing for you but the use-case you have will benefit from doing this I think.